# ValueError: could not convert string to float:?

Tags: python

I have a dataset with object type, which was imported as a txt file into Jupyter Notebook. But now I am trying to plot some auto-correlation for an individual column and it is not working.

My first attempt was to convert the object columns to float but I get the error message:

```
could not convert string to float: ?
```

How do I fix this?

Okay this is my script:

```
book = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv',  parse_dates=True)
t= str(book.Global_active_power)
t

'0          4.216\n1           5.36\n2          5.374\n3          5.388\n4          3.666\n5           3.52\n6          3.702\n7            3.7\n8          3.668\n9          3.662\n10         4.448\n11         5.412\n12         5.224\n13         5.268\n14         4.054\n15         3.384\n16          3.27\n17          3.43\n18         3.266\n19         3.728\n20         5.894\n21         7.706\n22         7.026\n23         5.174\n24         4.474\n25         3.248\n26         3.236\n27         3.228\n28         3.258\n29         3.178\n           ...  \n1048545    0.324\n1048546    0.324\n1048547    0.324\n1048548    0.322\n1048549    0.322\n1048550    0.322\n1048551    0.324\n1048552    0.324\n1048553    0.326\n1048554    0.326\n1048555    0.324\n1048556    0.324\n1048557    0.322\n1048558    0.322\n1048559    0.324\n1048560    0.322\n1048561    0.322\n1048562    0.324\n1048563    0.388\n1048564    0.424\n1048565     0.42\n1048566    0.418\n1048567    0.418\n1048568     0.42\n1048569    0.422\n1048570    0.426\n1048571    0.424\n1048572    0.422\n1048573    0.422\n1048574    0.422\nName: Global_active_power, Length: 1048575, dtype: object'
```

I believe the reason is that i have to format my column first for equal number of decimal places and then i can convert to float, but trying to format using this is not working for me

```
print("{:0<4s}".format(book.Global_active_power))
```

Comment: I can't see your computer screen from all the way over here - could you post your code?

Comment: Most likely, there is just non-number values in your dataset, that you need to clean up.

Comment: Error is obvious. plotting libraries like matplotlib expects data in float format and your dataframe has float data as strings(like '5.567').Please do preprocessing.

Comment: Do you mean you pickled objects into a txt? Or do you have stringified objects?

Comment: That error looks like you try to convert "?" to float in python2. As mentioned you should show your code. And add some debug messages showing the string you actually try to convert.

Answer (score 0):

The column contains a `?` entry. Clean this up (along with any other extraneous entries) and you should not see this error.